# How Borel sets make $\sigma$-algebra in a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

I am trying to wrap my head around random variables and can't prove the following questions:

> How, in a topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$, the collection of all Borel sets, say $\mathfrak{B}$, make a $\sigma$-algebra? And, Why is it the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{T}$?

In the introduction of the [Wikipedia entry of Borel sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set) these two statements appear. So, I'm using the definition of Borel set given there:

*A Borel set is any set in a topological space that can be formed from open sets through the operations of countable union, countable intersection, and relative complement.*

I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: A Borel set is any set in a topological space that can be formed from open sets through the **iterated** operations of countable union, countable intersection, and relative complement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes a $\sigma$-algebra because, directly from the definition you give, it is easy to see that it is closed under taking complements and countable intersection/union. Moreover, any $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{T}$ must contain all such sets as can be formed from the open sets in $\mathcal{T}$, so the Borel sets must be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{T}$, as all other such $\sigma$-algebras must contain it.

Answer (score -1):

A $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on a set $X$ is a subset of the powerset of $X$, $2^X$ and is defined by the following axioms:

1. $\emptyset$ and $X$ are in $\mathcal{A}$
2. $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under complement
3. $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under finite union

Let's prove that each of these axioms holds for the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space, where $\tau$ is a topology on the set $X$. As a quick reminder, let us list the axioms that define a topological space, where $\tau$ is also a subset of the $2^X$:

1. $\emptyset$ and $X$ are in $\tau$
2. $\tau$ is closed under arbitrary union
3. $\tau$ is closed under finite intersection

Once again, for convenience, let us remind ourselves of how the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $B$ is defined: as all sets resulting from the **iterated** (as pointed out by Michael Greinecker in the comments) application of three operations, namely countable union, countable intersection and complement to the open sets (the elements of $\tau$).

#### Axiom 1

Right off the bat, we can see that $\emptyset$ and $X$ are in $B$, since they are in $X$ by the definition of a topological space, and you can build them into the Borel $\sigma$-algebra trivially (e.g. union and intersection of the two).

#### Axiom 2

To prove that the complement of any element of $B$ is also in $B$, notice the following. The complement of the complement of a set is the set itself. The complement of a countable union is a countable intersection of complements. The complement of a countable intersection is a countable union of complements. As such, $B$ is closed under complement.

#### Axiom 3

A finite union is a countable union, which is one of the allowed operations to build a Borel set, so $B$ is closed under finite union.